# JS to disable a selectOneMenu primefaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

Js File:

```
$(document).on('change', '#DoctorsCreateForm\\:crm', function () {
    hideUfCrm(this, $('#DoctorsCreateForm\\:ufCrm'));
});

function hideUfCrm(crm, uf) {
    uf.disabled = crm.value === '' ? true : false;
}
```

XTHML Page:

```
<p:inputText id="crm" value="#{doctorsController.selected.crm}" title="#{bundle.CreateDoctorsTitle_crm}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateDoctorsRequiredMessage_crm}"  maxlength="7" >
    <f:attribute name="uf" value="#{uf}" />
    <f:validator validatorId="crmValidator" />
</p:inputText>
<p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateDoctorsLabel_ufCrm}" for="ufCrm" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="ufCrm" disabled="true"
                 value="#{doctorsController.selected.ufCrm}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateDoctorsRequiredMessage_type}" binding="#{uf}" >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{doctorsController.states}" var="state" itemLabel="#{state}"
                   itemValue="#{state}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I'm trying to disable the selectOneMenu, only if there's no text on (#crm) inputText, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does the browser console show? what does happen? And why not doing it server side?

Comment: It doesn't show any error and I put an alert to see if it's disabling the select, and yes, it returns me "true", but I don't know why it's not disabling in fact. Why should I do it server side?

Comment: Instead use the `widgetVar` attribute associated with `<p:selectOneMenu>` (thus add `widgetVar` to `<p:selectOneMenu>` such as `<p:selectOneMenu widgetVar="widget" ...>`). There are `disable()` and `enable()` functions in the DOM. Thus just do `if(!crm.value) {PF('widget').disable();} else {PF('widget').enable();}`. (All falsey values would pass the condition `if(!crm.value) {...}`. Doing it on the server-end would be better, by the way as JavaScript can easily be exploited by anyone).

Comment: Because if a user uses a browser development tool to 'enable' it again, he can use it. If you disable it serverside (and update the client) then the user will be able to post that field anyway. **never trust the client**